# why do I get error installing some python packages?

Tags: python, pip

Currently I'm trying to install `Image` package for python 2.7.14 on windows 7 64-bit. when I try `pip install Image`, it takes a while to answer and prompts an error as below (MJ is username):

```
C:\Users\MJ>pip install Image
Collecting Image
  Using cached image-1.5.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Image)
Collecting django (from Image)
  Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\mj\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-w95zen\django\setup.py", li
ne 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django\utils\version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\mj\appda
ta\local\temp\pip-build-w95zen\django\
```

for many of packages, I encounter problems while downloading or installing!
Is there anyway to get rid of these problems and develop under windows?

Comment: this can be 1) no `functools` module installed (`pip install functools` to fix) 2) `functools` version installed not compatible with the Image lib version (using `virtualenv` is the way to fix)

Comment: If `Image` needs to depend on a specific version of `functools` it should properly declare this as a versioned dependency in its `setup.py` or similar. Maybe raise this as a possible bug with the package's maintainer?

Comment: @Ivan I installed `functools` it did not help. I cannot understand the second way!

Comment: @tripleee It is not just `Image` but many packages have problem downloading or installing. is there any python proper package manager under Windows by which I can download and install packages and use them for development ,for example, by Pycharm?

Comment: As recommended above, `virtualenv` would be a good start if you are not already using that.

Comment: @MJay what are your versions of django / functools / image?

Comment: @tripleee I guess it is a package manager, I downloaded it using pip, how can I use it under pycharm?

Comment: @Ivan sorry I don't know how to find versions!

Comment: @MJay `pip show django`

Comment: @Ivan thank you for the hint. Django (1.11.9), functools (0.5) and image (1.5.17)